# fieldset ng-disabled is not working for button in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

`Fieldset ng-disabled` is not working on checkbox and button in *AngularJS*
 I have included my HTML code below:

```
<fieldset ng-disabled="isSaving"> 
   <div class="form-group erp-form-group">
     <label  class="col-erp-lb-2 control-label erp-label-control">
        Is Company:</label>
     <div class="col-erp-4 col-erp-checkbox" tourtip="
            click this to ..." tourtip-placement="left" tourtip-next-
              label="Continue" tourtip-step="1">
          <md-checkbox ng-model="isCompany" class="md-erp-checkbox"
          aria-label="Checkbox 1" ng-change="showContact()"></md-
         checkbox>              
     </div>
   </div>
  <div class="col-erp-gridinput-25">
    <div class="col-erp-gridinput-25">
      <input class="erp-grid-control"  placeholder="Click Add Button
      To  Add Item" readonly />
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: post your controller code

Comment: i am not doing anything inside controller..just setting isSaving varible true   var isSaving= true..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your code is valid, it may be caused by a bug in `angular-material` library, check [this issue on GitHub](https://github.com/angular/material/issues/2417) for reference.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have used `var isSaving = true`, instead of `$scope.isSaving= true`. check your controller.